# In Cocoa how to scale a NSImage with no transparency

Tags: cocoa, transparency, nsimage, alpha-transparency

I'm using this code to scale an image, everything works fine but the resulting image has a transparency in its properties and I just need an image with no transparencies and no alpha channels at all... Anyone knows how could I modify my code to obtain an image with no transparencies? 
Here my code:

```
- (void)scalePreviews:(NSString *)outputPath :(NSURL *)nomeImmagine :(CGFloat)size1   :(CGFloat)size2 :(NSString *)nomeIcona
{
NSImage *image = [[NSImage alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:[nomeImmagine path]];
if (!image)
    image = [[NSWorkspace sharedWorkspace] iconForFile:[nomeImmagine path]];


NSSize outputSize = NSMakeSize(size1,size2);
NSImage *anImage  = [self scaleImagePreviews:image toSize:outputSize];


NSString *finalPath = [outputPath stringByAppendingString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"/image-previews/%@",nomeIcona]];

//questo serve a creare la directory delle icone se gia' non esiste
NSFileManager *fileManager= [NSFileManager defaultManager];
if(![fileManager fileExistsAtPath:[outputPath stringByAppendingString:@"/image-previews"] isDirectory:nil])
    if(![fileManager createDirectoryAtPath:[outputPath stringByAppendingString:@"/image-previews"] withIntermediateDirectories:YES attributes:nil error:NULL])
        NSLog(@"Error: Create folder failed %@", [outputPath stringByAppendingString:@"/image-previews"]);

//  NSLog(@"finalPath: %@",finalPath);
NSData *imageData = [anImage TIFFRepresentation];

NSBitmapImageRep *rep = [NSBitmapImageRep imageRepWithData:imageData];

NSData *dataToWrite = [rep representationUsingType:NSPNGFileType properties:nil];

[dataToWrite writeToFile:finalPath atomically:NO];


}





- (NSImage *)scaleImagePreviews:(NSImage *)image toSize:(NSSize)targetSize
 {
       if ([image isValid])
        {

          NSSize imageSize = [image size];
         float width  = imageSize.width;
         float height = imageSize.height;
         float targetWidth  = targetSize.width;
        float targetHeight = targetSize.height;
        float scaleFactor  = 0.0;
        float scaledWidth  = targetWidth;
        float scaledHeight = targetHeight;

        NSPoint thumbnailPoint = NSZeroPoint;

        if (!NSEqualSizes(imageSize, targetSize))
        {
            float widthFactor  = targetWidth / width;
            float heightFactor = targetHeight / height;

            if (widthFactor < heightFactor)
            {
                scaleFactor = widthFactor;
            }
            else
            {
                scaleFactor = heightFactor;
            }

            scaledWidth  = width  * scaleFactor;
            scaledHeight = height * scaleFactor;

            newImage = [[NSImage alloc] initWithSize:targetSize];

            [newImage lockFocus];

            NSRect thumbnailRect;
            thumbnailRect.origin = thumbnailPoint;
            thumbnailRect.size.width = targetSize.width;  //scaledWidth;
            thumbnailRect.size.height = targetSize.height; //scaledHeight;

            [image drawInRect:thumbnailRect
                     fromRect:NSZeroRect
                    operation:NSCompositeSourceOver
                     fraction:1.0];

            [newImage unlockFocus];
        }

 }

 return newImage;

}
```

Comment: What do you mean by "transparency in its properties"? What color would you like to use in places where the original image is transparent? Have you tried just filling the rect with that color before drawing the original image? e.g. `[[NSColor whiteColor] set]; NSRectFill(thumbnailRect);`

Comment: I tryed to use your code but I still have that problem... With "transparency in its properties" I mean that also if the image has no transparency when I use it in a site that only accept images with no transparencies and no alpha channels I get an error saying it found transparencies... so I guess it must be in it's "DNA"... I don't know how... I also noticed that if I open the image with Photoshop and I give command "flatten image" the problem disappears...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a solution... I changed the representationUsingType... I used JPEGFileType so the image has no transparencies at all...

here the changed code:

> NSData *dataToWrite = [rep representationUsingType:NSJPEGFileType properties:nil];